# I want to send a value to another Excel file that performs some calculations and then get back the result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two Excel files. I want to send a value from File 1 to File 2, in File 2 will calculate a value according to some formula and parameters and return the result to File 1.

All of this should be done from File 1.

File 2 is locked and has only one cell unlocked where I can write a value to get a result.

[image: example image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck? Excel doesn't play nicely "transferring" data back and forth as you desire. It would probably be easier to just have everything contained in one workbook, maybe with hidden sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Data Table` functionality:
`Data` Tab > `Forecast` > `What-If Analysis` Tools > `Data Table`
[image: Data Table]

On the screenshot above I have used names for cells, but you can also use addresses.
It is important, that `Data Table` is defined in `File1` and it can use only local references. So your `Column Input Cell` must be in `File1`. In `File2` in a cell named `data` you refer to this `Column Input Cell`.
In the cell `D4` in the `File1` you enter a reference to the cell with calculation result from `File2`.
Then you select your data in `File1` (range C4:D7) and call `Data Table`.